# (Elasticsearch) How to change single cluster health from yellow to green

Tags: elasticsearch

After my Windows Server 2016 VM machine run out of storage , I added +100GB.

At the same time I've got Java auto-update , which also cause problem to my Elasticsearch v6.2.1 (i know its old but I cant change/upgrade it right now)

[image]

Due to not enough disk space and java auto-update, first I`ve got cluster red, then yellow, but now I cant get it to green, which makes partial query results due to Elasticsearch cluster health yellow.

Cluster health:

```
{
  "cluster_name": "abv",
  "status": "yellow",
  "timed_out": false,
  "number_of_nodes": 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes": 1,
  "active_primary_shards": 16,
  "active_shards": 16,
  "relocating_shards": 0,
  "initializing_shards": 0,
  "unassigned_shards": 15,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number": 51.61290322580645
}
```

Shard status:

```
index shard prirep state      docs store ip        node
abv   1     p      STARTED    5018   6mb 127.0.0.1 abv-node
abv   1     r      UNASSIGNED                      
abv   3     p      STARTED    4987   6mb 127.0.0.1 abv-node
abv   3     r      UNASSIGNED                      
abv   4     p      STARTED    5053   6mb 127.0.0.1 abv-node
abv   4     r      UNASSIGNED                      
abv   2     p      STARTED    5031   6mb 127.0.0.1 abv-node
abv   2     r      UNASSIGNED                      
abv   0     p      STARTED    5076 6.1mb 127.0.0.1 abv-node
abv   0     r      UNASSIGNED
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have replicas for the index and you need to switch off the replicas when using a single node cluster.

```
PUT _settings
{
  "index.number_of_replicas": 0
}
```

You should also think about setting up a template that can match all indices and set replicas to 0.

Comment: Okey it seems my problem was that the index was in "read only" state, i guess due to the problem with disk storage.

{
  "abv" : 
          "read_only_allow_delete" : "true"
        }
      
After i change this to false, and i change number of replicas to 0 , now is green state and everything is working fine.

I just don't understand the part with the template?

Comment: I am glad that you cluster has gone green. As for the templates, the mapping used by an index can be predefined in a template and the settings can also be set at this time, you can change the number of replicas for example.

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-template.html